# Can someone explain to me: appending elements to a target vs. assigning elements to a target?

Tags: javascript, html

I made two simple functions that you can see in  this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/oc06pxbq/1/)
. When the first button is clicked, I create an h3 element, I create some text, I append the text in the element, and I append the element in an id called results.
But, when you click on the second button I pretty much do the same thing, except I asked for the **innerHTML** of results and I assign it the h3 element. But, when I do that I get "**[object HTMLHeadingElement]** ". I was wondering why I get this response even though I feel like they're both doing the same thing

HTML:

```
<button id="click">
Click 
</button>
<button id="click2">
Click 2
</button>
<div id="results">
Hello
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('click').onclick = function()
{
 var a = document.createElement('h3');
 var b = document.createTextNode('This is some text!');
 a.appendChild(b);
 document.getElementById('results').appendChild(a);
}

document.getElementById('click2').onclick = function()
{
var a = document.createTextNode('This is some other text');
var b = document.createElement('h3');
var c = "";
b.appendChild(a);
c +=b

document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = c;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to convert an `object` into a `string` value, its `toPrimitive()` method will be called internally and that will return the string representation of the `object`. Here in our case the string representation of node object would be `"[object HTMLHeadingElement]"`. So that is being assigned as the innerHTML of the `#results` element.

Finally, if you want to extract the raw html string of an element then you have to access its `outerHTML` property. So the solution in your case is to get the `outerHTML` of the created element and assign it to the target's `innerHTML`.

```
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = b.outerHTML;
```

And your full code would be,

```
document.getElementById('click2').onclick = function() {
  var a = document.createTextNode('This is some other text');
  var b = document.createElement('h3');
  b.appendChild(a);
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = c.outerHTML;
}
```